# ionic how to display a dropdown of choices on button click

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am just starting with ionic framework, trying to redo an existing bootstrap / angular application to mobile as a hybrid app.

Is there an idiomatic way to do a dropdown menu in ionic? I have searched the ionic website/forums and also googled but no luck. Like [bootstrap single button dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns). I am OK with JavaScript but HTML/CSS is not my cup of tea.

Will appreciate your help.

--EDIT

Thanks TechMa9iac. I am trying to follow that line.

I am trying to make a 2-level dropdown using angular? I have modeled my data like in the ngSelect doc.

```
$scope.currSel = null;
$scope.metadata = [
    { proc: "Proc-1", board: "Alloc" },
    { proc: "Proc-1", board: "Manager" },
    { proc: "Proc-1", board: "Ops" },
    { proc: "Proc-2", board: "Alloc" },
    { proc: "Proc-2", board: "Manager" },
    { proc: "Proc-3", board: "Alloc" },
    { proc: "Proc-3", board: "Manager" }
];
```

HTML

```
<span>{{item.proc}}
<select ng-model="currSel"
        ng-options="item.board group by item.proc 
                        for item in metadata">
</select>
```

I show the `proc` value separately in html because the select text area shows only `board` value (the label in `select`).

Comment: You can use ionic select tag, and modify the css to make it look like a button. As you already specified that HTML/CSS IS NOT your cup of tea, i am posting it as a suggestion

Comment: When I *reenter* the directive with currSel={proc:"Proc-1", board:"Manager"} the select box invariably shows "Alloc" I don't know why it does not show "Manager". Changes within a single run of directive display right values :( I am no longer using ionic and using plain BS3.

Comment: Can you share a plunker ??

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/bAielFIZ3KXoaOtE5V9N?p=preview -- when you click on "home" the selector goes empty now.

Comment: Hey dinesh, can you just re-explain you problem from scratch.. I am finding it difficult to figure it out..

Comment: Surely. In problem terms, I have a grid that is keyed on combination of process+dashboard. That's what the selector is for. Codewise, the user-selection is owned by the main controller, and the directive updates that value on user actions. The change is visible in console log messages. However, the selector widget does not show the actual value of the user-selection. Also, when I click on "click-to-go-home" then the selector goes blank. I feel I mightb be missing some ng params somewhere.

Comment: Whenever the selector is being redrawn, the displayed value becomes the first option from the option-list

Comment: @TechMa9iac, got it to work! the ng-model must be a *reference* to one of the value array elements. Thanks a lot for your support!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the ng-model in an ng-options is an object, it must be an object reference to one of the value array / dict elements. It cannot be an `angular.copy`.

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bAielFIZ3KXoaOtE5V9N?p=preview)