# How to display dropdown menu from an icon button in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu with the options "share" and "delete" that displays from an icon button, but Ionic doesn't support it out of the box.

The button in question is like this:

```
<button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon-round" ng-click="show()"> 
</button>
```

I checked the question ([ionic how to display a dropdown of choices on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139785/ionic-how-to-display-a-dropdown-of-choices-on-button-click)) but it didn't help.

Maybe I need some Angular.js trick? I'm new in both Angular.js and Ionic framework.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking for is component [$ionicPopover](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopover/)

First create your component

```
$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('settings.html', {
    scope: $rootScope,
}).then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popup = popover;
});
```

Then you can show it from ng-click of your button

```js
 $scope.show= function($event) {
    $scope.popup.show($event);
 };
```

Ng-click of your function shall be updated also to send the $event paramenter

```js
 ng-click="show($event)"
```

Comment: As a note; while the snippet button is nice for formatting stuff; it's meant to be a replacement for jsfiddle, and kind of defeats the purpose if it isn't used like that.

Comment: hum it has been a while since I was not back on SO, and i've not looked at that. I'll in my further posts.

Comment: Exactly what a needed. I have to manually adjust the size of the Popover like this: `<ion-popover-view style="height: 120px">` which is 60px per option displayed in the Popover menu.